# Generate new ethereum account

Tags: ethereum, account

I'm developing a ethereum dapp that can automatically generate new accounts (wallet addresses) for users immediately after a registration button is clicked. 
It's pretty complicated for me since I'm a newbie in dapp development. Any solution on how to achieve this will highly be appreciated. I also have a Php script downloaded from GitHub [link](https://github.com/btelle/ethereum-php) though it could be handy for account generation since I'm using PHP as a back-end but still confused on how to use the script.

Requesting help on using the ethereum-PHP script for account generation will also be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: in web3.js, library have web3.personal.newAccount function. I think ethereum-php library have personal.newAccount function too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, but you should be able to do what you wish by using either Geth or Parity.  Personally, I prefer Parity.  They have good documentation and their API is easy to use.

[Parity.io](https://parity.io)

Answer (score 0):

If youre using web3 in front end you could simply use `web3.eth.accounts.create(<key>);` and save it on front end.

If youre using Metamask it has their own way of handling account creation out of the box.

You could use the `personal.newAccount()` in php-ethereum but in that case youre generating the private key at the server end which could be a possible.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use web3 for this task. In your sigup/register function file import web3 and connect it with you network. after that you can call two methods of web3 library.

one is `web3.eth.personal.newAccount('password')`: this function will generate account with keystore file . keystore file will be stored on network file directory.
second one is `web3.eth.accounts.create()`: this method will generate new account with private key of account which you can use to perform task on network .